# Is there an official method to do pre-departure briefings?

Tags: flight-training, flight-planning

We're using our simulator more at university, and while I might try to do a departure briefing (weather, route, etc.), it ends up fairly unstructured. None of us students have any formal qualifications and we are doing this for enjoyment, although we are keen to do it as authentically as possible.

*FAA has an example online, that I gather is maybe be a bit overdone:*

I've searched around for a recommended (check)list to go through for pre-departure briefings, but come out empty handed.

**Is there such a document endorsed by either the EASA or the FAA?**

Comment: There's no official CRM checklists that I know of, airlines develop their own. These are very structured for a reason, chances are the pilots have never met before, the structure ensures everyone knows what the others will do in the cockpit.

Comment: This article on how one company‘s briefing methods were reviewed and improvements suggested may be highly relevant: https://www.aerosociety.com/news/briefing-better/

Comment: @CptReynolds this seems to the best material to reference to, would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article linked below may be highly relevant, although it isn’t endorsed (directly) by any regulatory body. It describes how one company dissected their briefing concept and proposed improvements following a critical review of the adequacy, effectiveness and safety impact of their briefings in the operational context: [Briefing Better](https://www.aerosociety.com/news/briefing-better/)